# How to get Contact PhotoUrl in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, linkedin-api

In Salesforce I have created a few Contacts. And linked some of the contacts with LinkedIn profile. As soon as I link the contacts, the image display in Salesforce changes the profile image to that provided by LinkedIn. Basically I think it would work the same way if I linked it to Facebook or other social sites.

Now my requirement is to get the the PhotoUrl of the Contact. I went through this documentation [Contacts Standard Object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm). It shows there is a field "PhotoUrl", but when I make a query in SOQL using SOAP API, like "Select Name, PhotoUrl From Contact", this query fails and the response message tells that there is no such field as "PhotoUrl".

What am I missing? Is there any way I cant get the Photo?

Thanks

SOLUTION:
THE PROBLEM WAS WITH THE API VERSION 29. I HAD TO CHANGE IT TO 30. HOWEVER IT WAS TRICKY WITH SOAP API. I HAD TO CHANGE THE AUTHENTICATION ENDPOINT VERSION TO 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the version of salesforce API. It works for me in 30.0 and not in 29.0..

Comment: Glad to hear that. How did you manage to check and change the version of API? Please do give the steps a bit. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like I have to regenerate the WSDL file and import to project again. I will do that and send the update over.

Comment: Hello, I regenerated the Enterprise WSDL , but getting the same error. Can you please elaborate your answer a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a visualforce page, set your standard controller to Contact and then {!contact.PhotoUrl} will return the url.